# What happens when we create an instance of class in same class?

Tags: c#, class, instance

What will actually happens with references when we create an instance of the class in that same class like this:

```
public class Class1
{
  public Class1 instatnce;
}
```

And how it will look references when we'll try to get access to instance.

Comment: No different to when you create an instance in another class.  The question is quite unclear - what do you want to know?

Comment: You've not created the reference yet. You just declared a field of same type as enclosing type.

Comment: Depends if you are trying initialize it in the constructor, why not have a go?

Comment: @CharlesMager Wrong. You'll get StackOverflowException if field initialzer or constructor creates the instance.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Which he isn't doing in the provided sample.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, there are things to watch out for.  I was more interested in prodding to work out what the question actually was.  'What happens with references' isn't very clear.

Comment: @aevitas Yes, but that doesn't mean "No different to when you create an instance in another class". There is a subtle difference.

Comment: @CharlesMager I agree with you. Question isn't complete and unclear too. But we can't say "No different". It depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a problem. For example:

```
public class Class1
{
  public Class1 Instance {get; set;}
}

public class Class2
{
     public void Test()
     {
         Class1 class1 = new Class1();
         var nestedInstance = class1.Instance;
     }
}
```

Please read about singleton pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx
This let you to understand this case

Comment: A class referencing itself has nothing to do with singletons. Consider a class `Employee` which  has a property `public Employee Boss{get;set;}`. You can have many employees not only one, but all have a boss which is also an employee.

Comment: Singleton is good example of this operation. How this references works